# Find features of other layers that cover a feature (detecting overlays)

Tags: python, gis, qgis, pyqgis

In the following picture, you see 2 layers. Layer 1 is devided into smaller sections than layer 2, but all the features in layer 2 consist of one or more features from layer 1.

What I would like to do is, using python, iterate the features of layer 2 and detect all the features of layer 1 that this feature "covers" (poligonal intersection?). Thus I would be able to determine the numbers printed in red for each feature of layer 2.

Is there a simple code snippet to perform this task?

I've tried using `feature.geometry().intersection(base_feature.geometry())` and checking for `!= None`, but that does not seem to do the trick. It only checks points as far as I can tell, and I need to check if the area overlaps / intersects.

[image: Layers example]

Comment: Do you have the layers as (x,y) coordinate lists and in what format? Could you give the layers as text data?

Comment: Yes I do have a list of (x,y) coordinates for each polygon in each feature. I just need to check if the area (not necessarily the points) intersect. But if I do this manually it may be much slower - ideally QGIS has a function for that I trust?